# IBM Worklight - How to programmatically hide the splash image

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In the Android environment of my Worklight app I'm trying to hide the splash image manually. My use case is that I want to do some user validation actions in the background while the splash image is there. Once the user is validated then show a Dashboard screen, else show a  Login screen.

I know that in Java for splash image usage in Android is:

```
  super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
  super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(),2000);
```

This loads the splash image and hides it after 2 secs automatically. How can I do the same using JavaScript in Worklight?

**First time Login:**
 SplashScreen--> LoginPage-->dashBoard

**If user Authenticated: On Re-launch the app:**

SplashScreen --> LoginPage(Check for Authenticated or not)--> Automatically Navigate to DashBoard.

**Desired Task:**

SplashScreen(Do Authentication here true/False)--->(if True)---> DashBoard

I dont want to show Login page if user is authenticated, however it automatically navigate to DashBoard.

Answer (score 1):

try this Cordova API, it might work

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK with the current implementation of the splash image in Worklight 6.0, it is not possible to change the duration the splash image is displayed upon application launch.

This is something we would like to tackle in the future.

Comment: is there not the way in worklight to handle authentication on splashscreen? on Splashscreen and i want to check if user is already authenticated then no need to display login page for a while and user navigate to dashboard

Comment: No. Even if you manage to control the duration of the splash image, any implementation of what is being done in the background would have to be done natively, maybe using a Cordova plug-in (read the documentation). But again, you cannot control the during (however, do see if Anton's suggestion works for you in that regards).

Comment: thanks  Idan, so what trick should we follow for already authenticated user if we dont want to show Login page again in Worklight?