# IBM Worklight Android splash screen issue

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In my app I'm trying to hide the Splash Screen as per my needs, say after 3 secs. Which I could do easily in Phonegap. But in IBM Worklight its preventing that. 
I have already posted a question on this, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18864986/2520370)

When I dived more into the worklight library codes I have found a strange thing has been done,

in wlclient.js(file is read only and auto created on deploy.) following lines are written,

```
switch (getEnv()) {
        case WL.Env.ANDROID:
            // An injected interface from WLDroidGap.bindBrowser, used to dismiss the splash screen
            WLCordovaSplashScreenDialog.removeSplashScreen();
            WL.OptionsMenu.init();
            break;
```

If comment this line

```
WLCordovaSplashScreenDialog.removeSplashScreen();
```

my splash is running is like it should. But when app gets an update from server wlclient.js is recreated.

So is there other way out to hide my splash screen as per my wish not auto handled internally by IBM WL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as in your previous question. The current splash image implementation in Worklight does not provide the developer with the ability to choose when to hide the splash image.

We aim to change this, but obviously cannot commit to "when".

Answer (score 0):

in IBM MobileFirst you can manage splash screen , please refer to the documentation link [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen_javascript.html) that say (
In JavaScript code, you can use the `WL.App.showSplashScreen()`and `WL.App.hideSplashScreen()` methods to show and hide the splash screen.

You can choose to disable the automatic hiding of the splash screen by setting the option `autoHideSplash` to false in the `initOptions.js` file )